# Flutter base state management

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-state

I'm learning flutter by building app. I've implemented `BLoC pattern` to call rest api and provide data to the widgets. However per my understanding this is some data for the view which needs it. I want to have `Settings` button on most of the widgets where I can display current logged user information, able to change his language, theme, some specific selected data etc. Basically base state of the application. Is the `BLoC pattern` the approach for that? Or there is better way to that?

If yes, what is the way to do that. How can I handle multiple `StreamBuilder`, e.g. one for receiving the data from api and one to update the state?

I know I can do it dummy with singleton class and register it using `get-it plugin`, but if there is better way I would skip this.

Answer (score 0):

The recommendation of Google for managing state is to use the [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).
But always depends on what you need to do.

The author of Provider release a better version of provider called [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod). But I think is not ready for production yet.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes accross I've made it with `flutter_bloc` plugin. `BlocProvider` works on top of `provider` package mentioned by @Fer Buero Trebino

```
class ApplicationStateBloc extends Cubit<ApplicationState> {
  ApplicationStateBloc() : super(new ApplicationState());

  void updateWhatEver(Whatever whatever) {
    state.whatever = whatever;
    emit(state);
  }

  ApplicationState getCurrentState() => state;
}
```

Then in order to not deal with context not having the providers and stuff, register it on application load

```
void main() {
  setup();
  runApp(
    MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
            create: (context) => ApplicationStateBloc()
          )
        ],
        child: App())
  );
}
```

Then accessing the state in every widget is simple as

```
BlocProvider.of<ApplicationStateBloc>(context).getCurrentState()
```

Not sure if meets best practices, I'm open for comments, but for now it works.